# Send extra information in Backbone destory() method

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, tastypie

I am trying to send additional information in my backbone `destroy method`.
I have tried the following, but nothing seem to be work:

```
model.destroy({'contentType': 'application/json', 'data': {'wow': 1} })
model.destroy({'headers': {'wow': 1}})
model.destroy({'data': {'wow': 1}})
```

Can someone point out what i may be doing wrong ? I just cannot get it to work.

EDIT: After suggestion from @MorKadosh. I added processData to the request.

model.destroy({data: {wow: 1}, processData: true})

In the network request i can see that 'wow' is being sent as form data.

Now in the backend, i am using Tastypie. how do i access 'wow' in obj_delete of tastypie ?

Tasypie's obj_delete takes in bundle and **kwargs. I have printed out the following, None of which have 'wow' in them.

```
print bundle.data
for name, value in kwargs.items:
  print name, value
print bundle.request
```

Am i missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

`destroy` is simply using an AJAX `DELETE` method ($.ajax).
In addition to `data`, you will have to pass `processData:true` to allow jQuery to process the additional data.

That would look something like this:

```
    this.model.destroy({
        data: { wow:1 },
       processData:true
    });
```

You can see the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o49muxxb/2/
(open the network tab and see the request)

Comment: Hi @MorKadosh. Thank you for the fiddle. I do see in the network request. That "wow" is being sent in the form data. I have updated my question a lil more. Hopefully you can help.